# How do I make floating words?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I saw this on a Minecraft server, and would like to replicate it. Is this redstone? What is going on to achieve this floating text?

Here is an image.

[image]

Comment: This is a plugin of some variety. This is a bukkit server.

Comment: @Unionhawk, that does not seem to be the case (referring to answer below).

Comment: It's probably *automated* with a plugin on servers though, just because that would be more convenient than setting them by hand.

Comment: @ShadowZ. `/trunk` is not a vanilla command. You cannot add commands to vanilla. Therefore, this is a bukkit server QED.

Comment: The point is, you can repro the floating words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Source: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/command-blocks/2209069-1-8-new-floating-text-technique-no-more-need-for

You can do this in Vanilla Minecraft and also modded Minecraft. This is the way to do it in Vanilla. You only need one command:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Invulnerable:1b,NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,CustomNameVisible:1b,CustomName:<insert floating text>}
```

In this command, `Invulnerable` means you cannot kill it; `NoGravity` means it will not fall down or affected by gravity; `Invisible` is just making it invisible; and `CustomNameVisible` is the tag for the custom name to be shown. Add the words you want to be floating between `CustomName:` and `}` (or replace the words `<insert floating text>` with your desired words).

For example, the command to show the words "Arqade is bae" is:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Invulnerable:1b,NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,CustomNameVisible:1b,CustomName:Arqade is bae}
```

> Note: I currently do not have a computer next to me, so this part may not be 100% correct: You can also add other tags to customize the text even more:
>
> ```
> ...CustomName:{"text":"Arqade is bae","color":"dark_red","bold":"true"}}
> ```

Steps:

[image: !]

Result:

[image: !]

To delete the text, do

```
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,r=<radius>]
```

Comment: Can you put a screen shot or 2 showing the steps and the product?

Comment: For rpg purposes there is also the [title feature](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#title) which prints text in a quite good looking (and bigger) font. The displayed text can be [customized heavily](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Raw_JSON_text).

Comment: I suggest setting the Armor Stand as a `marker` as well by adding `marker:1` to the brackets. This will make the invisible armor stand have a tiny hitbox, so it doesn't interfere with anything else.

Comment: Any way to make coloured text, and any way of deleting the text?

Comment: @Jake I added that part as well.

Comment: @MrLemon I am not so sure how to add that... Can you please teach me? :P

Answer (score 0):

In versions after 1.6, the `{color:"dark_red"}` things don't work very well.

The only way to make them colored is either MCEdit or The Plugin "Holographic Displays" which I use on my server and so does my brother.

Answer (score -4):

By freezing (use barrier blocks if you are new to the Redstone community) invisible named horses. Quite hard to preform but very possible in Vanilla. Be sure to give the horse Resistance AsHighAsPossible. Basic (and not good for an server) but, well, I guess you just want to know how this thing works.